# Can't able to install .ipa into device although it is authorized?

Tags: ios, macos, ios9, itunes, ipa

I am trying to install an .ipa file into my device. Firstly the iTunes told me to authorise the device. Than I authorised it through store -> Authorise this device. But still I can't able to install the .ipa and it's still advising me to authorise the computer as below Photo. Is there anything else I missed ? If yes, what is it and how to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you added the UDID in your developer account?

Comment: Yes, It's already added to the developer account.

Comment: have you authorised your device in current System. Otherwise when you connect device to your system means it will show an alert like Trust this computer. You need to click on Trust.

Comment: I trusted it, but it won't providing me the access. :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are generating ad-hoc build. Your device needs to be provisioned for the application (whose `.ipa` file you are installing) for file to gets installed.

Get your device UUID part of the provisioning profile you are using for the application. Re-intall the updated provisioning profile on your machine and then re-generate the `.ipa`.

Comment: Yes, my UUID already added. I am trying to install the .ipa through sync from iTunes. While sync it's saying to authorise like Store > Authorise This Computer